# Sign In with Apple generated token ignores expiration time

Tags: apple-sign-in

I'm posting to https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token to generate a token, but it's ignoring the 'exp' value that I pass in the client_secret part, and is returning me a token that has a 9 minute expiration. Is there a trick to getting an ID token that lasts longer than that?

Comment: Short lasting id tokens with Apple Sign In seems to be a fact so far. I feel your pain. :). My frustrations elaborated here-- https://medium.com/better-programming/apple-sign-in-custom-servers-and-an-expiry-conundrum-d1ad63223870

Comment: So, just to be clear-- you've succeeded in getting id tokens with newer expiry date/times by this method? (Despite the fact that they are brief).